# Python read excel error: 'Book' object has no attribute 'extract_formulas'

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to read file from excel in this way:

```
import pandas as pd
import xlrd

data_xls = pd.read_excel('/Users/chloe.song/Documents/Projects/KO B2B/data/results_coke_08.xlsx', 'Single', index_col=None)
data_xls.to_csv('your_csv.csv', encoding='utf-8')
```

When I am running the code line by line, I am getting this error for the last line: AttributeError: 'Book' object has no attribute 'extract_formulas'

I cannot read or export any excel file, but 'read_csv' and 'to_csv' work well.

Comment: Hello, after your read_excel, are you able to print your data ?

Comment: @PierreK No, the problem is I cannot even read the excel... always show that error.

Comment: you should add a sample of your xlsx file

Comment: @PierreK my issue has been solved just because of interpreter setting. Thanking for your answer.